# why the result is 1?

Tags: c++, containers, stdvector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> sum(1);
    sum.push_back(1);
    sum[0] = 1;
    std::cout << sum[1];
}
```

why the result is 1?
I have never define sum[0].

Comment: "_why the result is 1? I have never define sum[0]._" `std::vector<int> sum(1);` creates a vector having a single, default constructed element, at index `0`.

Comment: If you **hadn't** added enough members, `sum[0]` and `sum[1]` would have been illegal array accesses, which cause Undefined Behavior.

Comment: A tip when you're trying to figure out where a value is coming from: use **different** values in different places. In the code in the question, `sum.push_back(1)` and `sum[0]` = 1;` are  both putting `1` somewhere. If one of those put a `2` in, it might be clearer where the `1` or the `2` was coming from.

Answer (score 7):

This line creates a vector with size 1, with a value of zero

```
std::vector<int> sum(1);   // sum now contains { 0 }
```

Then after your `push_back`

```
sum.push_back(1);          // sum now contains { 0, 1 }
```

Then you assign over the first value

```
sum[0] = 1;                // sum now contains { 1, 1 }
```